# how can solve ANTLR Runtime version error in pyspark?

Tags: python, pyspark, runtime-error, antlr4

I want run a code with pyspark that read a csv file. The code is :

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = (SparkSession.builder.appName("4-1")      
         .getOrCreate())

csv_file = "departuredelays.csv"

schema = "`date` STRING, `delay` INT, `distance` INT, `origin` STRING, `destination` STRING"
df = spark.read.csv(csv_file, schema, inferSchema=True, header=True)
```

but when I run that it accrued this errore:

```
An error occurred while calling o28.schema.
: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.AbstractSqlParser.parse(ParseDriver.scala:107)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.AbstractSqlParser.parseTableSchema(ParseDriver.scala:76)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType$.fromDDL(StructType.scala:543)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.schema(DataFrameReader.scala:92)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: java.io.InvalidClassException: org.antlr.v4.runtime.atn.ATN; Could not deserialize ATN with version 3 (expected 4).
    at org.antlr.v4.runtime.atn.ATNDeserializer.deserialize(ATNDeserializer.java:56)
    at org.antlr.v4.runtime.atn.ATNDeserializer.deserialize(ATNDeserializer.java:48)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.SqlBaseLexer.<clinit>(SqlBaseLexer.java:1603)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: java.io.InvalidClassException: org.antlr.v4.runtime.atn.ATN; Could not deserialize ATN with version 3 (expected 4).
    ... 19 more
  File "E:\spark-3.3.2-bin-hadoop3\python\lib\py4j-0.10.9.5-src.zip\py4j\protocol.py", line 326, in get_return_value
  File "E:\spark-3.3.2-bin-hadoop3\python\pyspark\sql\utils.py", line 190, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "E:\spark-3.3.2-bin-hadoop3\python\lib\py4j-0.10.9.5-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 1321, in __call__
  File "E:\spark-3.3.2-bin-hadoop3\python\pyspark\sql\readwriter.py", line 118, in schema
    self._jreader = self._jreader.schema(schema)
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "E:\spark-3.3.2-bin-hadoop3\python\pyspark\sql\readwriter.py", line 50, in _set_opts
    self.schema(schema)  # type: ignore[attr-defined]
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "E:\spark-3.3.2-bin-hadoop3\python\pyspark\sql\readwriter.py", line 496, in csv
    self._set_opts(
  File "F:1.py", line 14, in <module>
    df = spark.read.csv(csv_file, schema, inferSchema=True, header=True)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o28.schema.
: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.AbstractSqlParser.parse(ParseDriver.scala:107)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.AbstractSqlParser.parseTableSchema(ParseDriver.scala:76)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType$.fromDDL(StructType.scala:543)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.schema(DataFrameReader.scala:92)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: java.io.InvalidClassException: org.antlr.v4.runtime.atn.ATN; Could not deserialize ATN with version 3 (expected 4).
    at org.antlr.v4.runtime.atn.ATNDeserializer.deserialize(ATNDeserializer.java:56)
    at org.antlr.v4.runtime.atn.ATNDeserializer.deserialize(ATNDeserializer.java:48)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.SqlBaseLexer.<clinit>(SqlBaseLexer.java:1603)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: java.io.InvalidClassException: org.antlr.v4.runtime.atn.ATN; Could not deserialize ATN with version 3 (expected 4).
    ... 19 more
```

and

```
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
ANTLR Tool version 4.8 used for code generation does not match the current runtime version 4.12.0
ANTLR Runtime version 4.8 used for parser compilation does not match the current runtime version 4.12.0
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Have you tried to change the versions as suggested?

Comment: @Memristor, How can I do this?

Comment: is there a solution for this, I am facing this error with spark 3.3.2 when I am trying to create dataframe in my tests?

Comment: @Vishal, I can not solve this problem. you must delete apache spark and install again